# How to match color of my notification icon with the color of the status bar?

Tags: android

On my HTC wildfire, the status bar is black. Thus I had to make sure that my notification icons have bright colors (white, yellow) for them to look legible. I'm pretty certain the choice of the status bar's background color is the prerogative of the manufacturer/telco. How can I ensure that the icon is legible in all phones (given that I don't know the color of the status bar in advance) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow [the guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html)!

I have a Nexus S, the status bar is dark, and while not every app has updated its notification icons to the new 2.3 look, those designed properly according to the 2.2 and below guidelines look fine.